# Page.evaluate vs Page.waitForFunction in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

what's diffrence between `page.evaluate` and  `page.waitForFunction` in puppeteer

Comment: You can find an answer on here.
page.evaluate :https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

page.waitForFunction: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args

Answer (score 14):

Differences:

- `page.evaluate` will run the code once and return data.
- `page.waitForFunction` will run the code repeatedly until the code returns `truthy` values.